# ZF2 aka Apigility SQL with predicates

Tags: sql, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm attempting to use Predicates within ZF2 in order to query on a `date` type column named `column_date`

Nothing seems to work for the any columns and I am so new I am unsure where to start..

```
        $query = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();

        $predicate = new Where();
        $query->where($predicate->equalTo('user_id' , $params['user_id']));
        $query->where($predicate->equalTo('super_type', 'steep'));
        $query->where($predicate->greaterThan('column_date',$dateRangeArray[0]));
        $query->where($predicate->lessThan('column_date', $dateRangeArray[1]));

        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select($query);
        $resultArr = $rowset->toArray();
```

This is returning things that have incorrect `user_id`, incorrect `column_date` in them.. why?

`dateRangeArray` looks like this :

`dateRangeArray[0] = 2014-09-01
dateRangeArray[1] = 2015-09-01`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem but try this:

`$predicate = new Where();
$predicate->equalTo('user_id' , $params['user_id'])
          ->equalTo('super_type', 'steep')
          ->greaterThan('column_date',$dateRangeArray[0])
          ->lessThan('column_date', $dateRangeArray[1]);`

`$query->where($predicate); `

Comment: @Demo , I'm still wondering why the chaining is required.. however I did get something working.  Everything works except the `greaterThan` `lessThan` query parts.. I had to generate a raw Query String for those and inject it.

Comment: Oh, well the chaining isn't needed. My point was that only one `$query->where(...)` was needed. Now I realize that in greater than and less than you are comparing dates, so maybe that's the problem.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is to strip the `-` in the dates(also save them this way in the db) and you'll compare integers (20140901)

Comment: Ok and a wild guess try: 
`$query->where(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression("DATEDIFF(day, 'column_date', {$dateRangeArray[0]}) > ?", 0));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working properly within Apigility's TableGateway

```
    //parses into an array of YYYY-MM-DD
    $dateRangeArray = $transformer->parseDateRange($activity_date_range, "ymd");

    $start_date_formatted = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateRangeArray[0]));
    $end_date_formatted = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateRangeArray[1]));


    // Query 
    $query = $this->getSql()->select()
        ->where->equalTo('user_id' , $user_id)
        ->where->greaterThanOrEqualTo('field_date ', $start_date_formatted)
        ->where->lessThanOrEqualTo('fieldy_date',$end_date_formatted);


    $rowset = $this->select($query);
    $resultArr = $rowset->toArray();

    return $resultArr;
```